# Music Hall or music hall

Tags: capitalization

Music Hall or music hall for the general type of British theatrical entertainment, rather than any particular entertainment centre.

Answer (score 2):

Well, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_hall) says "music hall".

And [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Music+Hall+entertainment%2Cmusic+hall+entertainment&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMusic%20Hall%20entertainment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmusic%20hall%20entertainment%3B%2Cc0) produces consistently higher scores for the (case sensitive) phrase "music hall entertainment" than for "Music Hall entertainment". At least, since the fifties. Before that, no great difference.

Not sure if there's much else to say.

Comment: Thanks.  I trust Google Ngram Viewer more than Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why music hall should be capitalised differently to any other form of entertainment. In the following sentences...

- He's a famous x performer
- I'm very interested in x
- We went to the x last night

You wouldn't (I think) capitalise x if it were theatre, cinema, ballet, circus, etc. Why should music hall be any different?

You'd only capitalise it if it were part of a proper name, rather than describing a genre of performance or a type of venue - e.g. Radio City Music Hall.